# Loop para achar combinação correta

Tags: python, loop

Recentemente construí um algoritmo simples para achar combinações corretas com a seguinte url:

```
https://api-main.ecobonuz.com/api/v1/bus-cards/checkInfo?number=1395037673&card=5c8b1160a453ea0ae5e0fdfd&busCardId=&checkBusCard=true&ein=
```

Precisava que o parâmetro **number** começasse em `1000000000` e fosse até `9000000000`. Caso o status code for `200` ou `True`, gostaria de armazenar o número usado na requisição.

Por enquanto eu tenho apenas este código:

```
import requests 
import json

numero=

Url='https://api-main.ecobonuz.com/api/v1/bus-cards/checkInfo?number='+numero+'&card=5c8b1160a453ea0ae5e0fdfd&busCardId=&checkBusCard=true&ein='

r = requests.get(Url)

print(r.text)
```

Sou iniciante então se houve algum equívoco, por favor me informe os problemas para enriquecer meu aprendizado.

Comment: você quer fazer 8 bilhões de requisições http, é isso?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Para realizar múltiplas requisições alterando o valor de **number** entre X e Y, basta percorrer os números dentro de um laço `for` utilizando a função [`range`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_range.asp) (retorna números entre X e Y) e depois enviar a requisição.

```
url = 'https://api-main.ecobonuz.com/api/v1/bus-cards/checkInfo?number={}&card=5c8b1160a453ea0ae5e0fdfd&busCardId=&checkBusCard=true&ein='

for number in range(1000000000, 9000000001):
     response = requests.get(url.format(number))
```

---

Uma melhoria que você pode fazer no seu código é criar um dicionário para guardar todos os parâmetros passados na requisição separadamente.

Dessa forma, o seu código ficará muito mais organizado.

```
params = {
    'number': None,
    'card': "5c8b1160a453ea0ae5e0fdfd",
    'busCardId': '',
    'checkBusCard': True,
    'ein': ''
    }

url = 'https://api-main.ecobonuz.com/api/v1/bus-cards/checkInfo'
```

---

Para verificar se o código da resposta foi 200, basta verificar o atributo `status_code` com uma condicional. Caso a condição seja verdadeira, basta adicionar à uma lista o número usado.

```
if requests.get(url, params = params).status_code == 200:
    numbers.append(number)
```

Veja abaixo o código completo:

```
import requests

params = {
    'number': None,
    'card': "5c8b1160a453ea0ae5e0fdfd",
    'busCardId': '',
    'checkBusCard': True,
    'ein': ''
    }

url = 'https://api-main.ecobonuz.com/api/v1/bus-cards/checkInfo'

start = 1000000000
stop = 9000000000

numbers = []

for number in range(start, stop + 1):

    params["number"] = number
    response = requests.get(url, params = params)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        numbers.append(number)
        print("Número encontrado:", number)
```

Comment: não sei quanto didático é ensinar alguém que não sabe sequer usar uma variável que está tudo ok fazer um atauq de froça bruta contra uma API, tentando fazer 8 bilhões de requisições - mesmo que cada requisição leve 20 segundos, isso seriam mais ou menos quase 10 anos - então tem que ser didático também e explicar a questão de recursos computacionais e de rede, e as questões éticas de tentar advinhar códigos de desconto por força bruta. 

Eu recomendaria abordar esses pontos na sua resposta.

Comment: Tem razão, eu li a pergunta mas não me toquei sobre o que ele estava tentando fazer. O site proíbe este tipo de pergunta aqui ?

Comment: acho que é proibido não é - vai de cada um saber como responder mesmo - se for realmente um crime explícito, aí é contra a lei - e não iportam as regras do site.
No caso,  a pessoa só está com a intenção, mas quer experimentar - acho que vale só chamar a atenção.

Answer (score -1):

Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow, Jacksuel!

```py
import requests 
import json

codigos=[] # lista vazia que armazenará os códigos

for i in range(1000000000, 9000000001): # loop entre os números pretendidos
    url=f'https://api-main.ecobonuz.com/api/v1/bus-cards/checkInfo?number={i}&card=5c8b1160a453ea0ae5e0fdfd&busCardId=&checkBusCard=true&ein=' # cria o URL com o número que o loop está a processar
    r = requests.get(url)
        if r.status_code == 200: # se a resposta for 200...
            codigos.append(i) # adiciona o número (i.e. 1000000006) à lista "códigos"
```

Comment: Por favor Carlos, não ponha apenas o código da solução na resposta. Explique o que você fez para que o autor da pergunta e outros possam entender.

Comment: @JeanExtreme002 comentei o código, amigo! Mas vi a tua resposta e percebi. Obrigado!